# basic ajax function not working

Tags: ajax, jsp, tomcat

i'm learning Ajax and i'm facing some problem with this very basic function:

function fetchData(url, objectID){

```
  var pageReqtest=null;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)pageRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
  if(window.ActiveXObject)pageRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  else return false;

  pageRequest.onreadystatechange= function(){
      var object=document.getElementById(objectID);
      object.innerHTML = pageRequest.responseText;
   }

  pageRequest.open("GET",url,true);
  pageRequest.send(null);
```

}

And then i have:

```
<div id="control" onclick="fetchData('data.jsp','message');">Click here for Ajax!</div>
```

But unfortunatelly its not working, the function though is correctly called.

I have my project in Eclipse and i'm running this on Tomcat 6, the page data.jsp its a single line of html, the data.jsp is positioned at the same lavel as the page where the javascript  function is written

Do you have some advice?

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is that it is a syntax error caused by your misspelling of `function`:

```
pageRequest.onreadystatechange= fucntion(){
```

This would cause the Javascript not to be parsed, so your function would never be defined.

---

On a different note, there are a couple of other little errors that, while they might not prevent your code working, might make your life difficult.

```
var pageReqtest=null;
```

Elsewhere you call the variable `pageRequest`. Be consistent: at the moment, you are creating a global variable called `pageRequest` and completely ignoring the local one `pageReqtest`.

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)pageRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
if(window.ActiveXObject)pageRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else return false;
```

If the browser has both `window.XMLHttpRequest` and `window.ActiveXObject`, you will create both, first the XMLHttpRequest object, then you will overwrite it with the ActiveXObject. This isn't what you want – it's suboptimal and it's better to use the proper XMLHttpRequest if it's available.

The quick way to do this is to make the second line `else if` at the beginning.

And you miss out the id in the `getElementById` call:

```
 var object=document.getElementById();
```

I think this should be:

```
 var object = document.getElementById(objectID);
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply, i have corrected all the typos and now its partially working, i'm now using an absolute url onclick="fetchData('WEB-INF/views/data.jsp','message');" to get the file data.jsp but tomcat gives me a 404, also, i'm usng spring framework and when i click on the div with th event handler, it activates a controller, which normally applies only if i would send a form or click o a link which adressess that controller

Comment: @JBoy That's a different question. I don't know the first thing about Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

beside wrong spelling as mentioned by lonesomeday

you also have missing parameter here `var object=document.getElementById();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like others beat me to it, but in any case, here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smendola/BcMMn/

As they said, typos...